# Cannot resize vector to 1765880295

Tags: c++

I want to allocate a vector of size 1765880295 and so  i used resize(1765880295) but the program stops running.The adjact problem would be code block not responding.

what is wrong?

Although the max_size gives 4294967295 which is greater than 1765880295 the problem is still the same even without resizing the vector.

Comment: What do you mean "the problem is still the same even without resizing the vector"? The problem *is* with resize, isn't it? So how can it be same "without" it?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is stored in the vector -- for example, a 32-bit pointer or uint32, the size of the vector (number of elements * size of each element) will exceed the maximum addressable space on a 32-bit system.

Comment: The vector store characters so 1765880295 equals 1765880295 characters  since each character equal one byte,right.

Comment: "each character equals one byte": is this Unicode or plain old `char`s?

Answer (score 0):

The `max_size` is dependent on the implementation (some may have 1073741823 as their max_size). But even if your implementation supports a bigger number, the program will fail if there is not enough memory.

For example: if you have a `vector<int>`, and the `sizeof(int) == 4 // bytes`, we do the math, and...

`1765880295 * 4 bytes = 7063521180 bytes ≈ 6.578 gygabytes`

So you would require around 6.6GiB of free memory to allocate that enormous vector.